# How well does the Xcode 7 UI Tests integrate with Xcode Bots? Does it display the UI testing steps?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-bots

Has anyone integrated the new Xcode UI Tests (XCUITest) with Xcode Bots yet? I'm specifically interested in how the test results are displayed. When the tests are run in Xcode itself, the Test Reports section lays out step-by-step what happened in each test case, complete with screenshots. This applies for both cases that passed, and failed. Do the Xcode Bots results do anything similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't see much on the web interface: [image]

But you'll see similar reports on Xcode for each bot run: all the steps + screenshots were applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it sounds like it's essentially the same as the Test reports that Xcode already shows anyway when CI isn't connected.

Comment: Do you have a sample screenshot you could share of how the web interface looks compared to the Xcode view?

Comment: @ApopheniaOverload I uploaded image from web. And indeed the detailed report is exactly the same as you see on local test runs.

Comment: Did you have to do any extra setup to have your XCTestCase tests to run? The app from my understanding runs under a system account and wouldn't run as the user account specified in the bot?

Comment: @mservidio I don't remember having to do any fancy setup beside what was necessary to run UITests target.